# iPhone Radio Streaming for WMA audio files

Tags: iphone, streaming, audio-streaming, internet-radio, wma

I need to implement iphone streaming functionality for WMA audio files from the server. iPhone can support only mp3, wav, aac audio files. But I need to play wma audio streaming for the iphone radio application.

Can anyone tell me how to do this things. I really thankful for your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically impossible unless you feel like writing your own decoder. The iPhone doesn't support WMA and that's kind of the end of it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.,

Do you have any example which converts the live streaming wma audio file into mp3 to play on iphone?

Comment: I can stream simple mp3 and aac file using Audio Streamer. I have also configured FFMPEG. Can you tell me how to use FFMPEG and MMSLib library to convert live streaming in mp3 format from wma.

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with Noah Witherspoon. Just adding one step, for handling audio streaming you should look at [this](http://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the given example only supports the mp3 audio files. Can you help me for playing wma audio streaming files in iphone?

Comment: I can stream simple mp3 and aac file using Audio Streamer. I have also configured FFMPEG. Can you tell me how to use FFMPEG and MMSLib library to convert live streaming in mp3 format from wma.

Answer (score 1):

For wma you should use the FFmpeg library. FFmpeg will be able to decode wma audio streams and also connect to mms audio streams.

If you do a little research you'll find ways to compile static FFmpeg libraries for the iOS platform. Once you have the static FFmpeg libraries in place you can connect to audio streams and start decoding. To play the decoded audio packets you'll need to use the AudioQueue framework. Basically you pass the decoded audio data to AudioQueue and tell it to play the buffers filled with the decoded data FFmpeg gave you.

Comment: I am able to play the streaming but that is not working 100% fine and have some problem when playing and sometimes it has delay when playing. Can you advice how to solve that issue?