# how to play wma mp3 files

Tags: iphone, wma

I need to create a simple media player that can stream internet radio stations in WMA, MP3 and AAC formats as part of a bigger app.

I was wondering if someone could please give me some pointers on where to start and how to go about tackling each of these formats? never really handled this topic before..

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [iPhone Radio Streaming for WMA audio files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600409/iphone-radio-streaming-for-wma-audio-files)

Answer (score 1):

We've made up a few audio streamers before, and we've favored the Audio Streamer libraries by Matt Gallagher. You can get the source at the following link:

https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer

You should also check out Apple's Audio Stream example below which will give some pointers as to some of the frameworks and libraries you will need to work this out.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AudioFileStreamExample/Introduction/Intro.html