# On demand RTSP streaming FFMPEG iPhone

Tags: ios, ffmpeg

We are using FFmpeg for real time streaming in iPhone.
For testing purpose we have hosted a video on local server.When we try to start stream avformat_open_input method always return error code -5.
I have read some where that is is I/O error but the same URL working fine on VLC media player.
If we start streaming on VLC first then play it on iPhone it works fine.
I am not getting where I am wrong the IP address and network connection both are fine.

Comment: First make sure that your streaming file not should be **.wma** file.

Comment: Thanks for your response iPatel but how the format will effect the streaming.The same video is stream fine on VLC and it works on my iPhone only if I play it on VLC first.Is there any API in ffmpeg which could initialize streaming if its not started.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600409/iphone-radio-streaming-for-wma-audio-files and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21903789/add-ffmpeg-library-in-ios

Comment: I have verified the video format is not .wma.This is a real time streaming the feed data came form camera and we access it from server

Comment: I am using TCP as rtsp_transport.Should I use UDP